# Python SQLAlchemy ORM where clause with two column value

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am testing Python ORM where clause matching two column name, with single column matching works.

with two column matching its giving the error message.

```
row = session.execute(select(User).where(User.name == "squidward")  and  User.fullname='Squidward Tentacles')
```

How to match two column in `SQLAlchemy` ORM?

Thanks

Comment: try with `session.query(User).filter_by(name="squidward", fullname='Squidward Tentacles')`. And read the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/quickstart.html) of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`and_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_) element to combine expressions in a clause.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
row = session.execute(select(User).where(
    sa.and_(
        User.name == "squidward", 
        User.fullname == 'Squidward Tentacles'
    )
)
```